# Reducing count value in span based on number of characters entered in textarea

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to implement a character counter which displays number of chars a user can enter inside a text area using jQuery. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="questionTextBox"  placeholder="Enter question e.g. How do I as for a pay raise?" name="data[Qna_question][question_text]"></textarea>

<span id="noOfChar">128</span> characters remaining
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery("#questionTextBox").keypress(function () {

   var qText = jQuery("#questionTextBox").val();

   if(qText.length <= 127) {
    jQuery("#noOfChar").html(128 - qText.length - 1);
   } else {
       jQuery("#questionTextBox").val(qText.substring(0,128));
   }

  });
```

});

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cy667/

It's not working correctly.

1. When it reaches 128 character it should not take any more values
2. When I delete characters, counter should increase. It is not increasing when I delete first few characters after reaching 128 limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use all three jQuery key events to catch everything user does with his keyboard.

This should fix your problems: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/Cy667/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function updateCount ()
    {
        var qText = jQuery("#questionTextBox").val();

       if(qText.length < 128) {
           jQuery("#noOfChar").html(128 - qText.length);
       } else {
           jQuery("#noOfChar").html(0);
           jQuery("#questionTextBox").val(qText.substring(0,128));
       }
    }

    $("#questionTextBox").keyup(function () {
        updateCount();
    });
    $("#questionTextBox").keypress(function () {
        updateCount();
    });
    $("#questionTextBox").keydown(function () {
        updateCount();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But using keyup has a bad user experience when a user keep a key pressed. All characters are entered and then after keyup they are removed. Is there any other way to do it?   BTW, our IF conditions are same :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you can just use textarea's maxlength attribute

`<textarea maxlength="128"></text>`

For the second problem, I tried that it didn't work by pressing functional keys (e.g.,  backspace, shift, etc), so you can bind the function to textarea's *onchange* listener.

Comment: And  onPropertyChange listener could capture the value changes triggered by script.